# Call to 'tap' failed. An unknown server-side error occurred. Original error: *** - [__ NSArrayM insertObject: atIndex:]: object cannot be nil"

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-desktop

I am using Appium desktop (App Version: 1.22.0), iOS simulator, and real iPhone to establish a session and interact with the app. The connection is established successfully, and I can interact with the app through Appium, except when a popup appears; in this case, when I try to tap on the popup buttons, this error appears:

```
"Call to 'tap' failed. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: *** - [__ NSArrayM insertObject: atIndex:]: object cannot be nil"
```

[image]

This error happens only when I try to perform "tap" through Appium. I can perform tap manually in the Simulator or on the iPhone

I have read several comments over the internet, and some say they fixed that problem by uninstalling and installing Appium or using a different version. Nothing has worked for me, I have tried Appium 1.20.2, 1.21.0, and 1.22.0, and the problem persists.
I am still investigating this issue, but I have run out of resources. If it has happened to you or you know how to solve it, please share the information with me.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing Appium v1.22.2 via npm and setting Appium-WebDriverAgent on that path. I don't know if it will be the ideal solution, but it worked for me.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not about Appium v1.22.2 or Appium below version. Below code will work. Just you need to switch to native view if you are on webview screen and use  TouchAction class to perform the tap action on screen.

```
    switchContextBasedOnString("NATIVE_APP");
    
    Point p = iosDriver.findElement(findBy("allowElement")).getCenter();
    int x = p.getX();
    int y = p.getY();
    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(iosDriver);
    action.tap(PointOption.point(x, y)).perform();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where I couldn't interact with alert views, it finds element but when tries to interact with a button it throws the error mentioned above. I run tests on real devices - after updating appium version to v1.23.0-beta.0 it can interact with element.